# How to send unicode characters using python gsmmodem module?

Tags: python, unicode, sms, gsm

I'm trying to send unicode characters using `python-gsmmodem-new` v0.12 module.
https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/python-gsmmodem-new-0.12/autoapi/modem/index.html 
It works find when I'm sending GSM-7 messages.

However, it shows `"Unable to set SMS encoding (enocoding UCS2 not supported)"` when I'm trying to send a unicode message.

```
try:
    modem.sendSms('3473438473', '测试')
except TimeoutException:
    sys.stderr.write('Time out.\n')
except CommandError:
    sys.stderr.write('Failed.\n')
```

Below is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/user/Sites/mobilesmsPython/mobileSMS.py", line 651, in <module>
main()

File "/Users/user/Sites/mobilesmsPython/mobileSMS.py", line 389, in main
modem.sendSms('3473438473', '测试')

File "/Users/user/Sites/mobilesmsPython/gsmmodem/modem.py", line 919, in sendSms
self.smsEncoding = 'UCS2'

File "/Users/user/Sites/mobilesmsPython/gsmmodem/modem.py", line 712, in smsEncoding
raise ValueError('Unable to set SMS encoding (enocoding {0} not supported)'.format(encoding))

ValueError: Unable to set SMS encoding (enocoding UCS2 not supported)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm getting the same error....